# iframe website refused to connect, x-frame-options is deny

Tags: html, iframe

Is there any way to display a website (that is not mine) in iframe when it refuses to connect? I have no idea what x-frame-options is, and I was wondering if there is anyway to bypass that.

Comment: There is something called [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and it exists to prevent this (some people try to hack like this!) If you can, you need to ask the owner to allow you specifically from your domain to allow you to use their website embed.

Comment: @Rojo Oh okay thanks!

Comment: A simple web search for "x-frame-options" brings up about 5,170,000 Results...

Comment: Thanks for the question. Even though it's very general it was helpful to me by mapping iframe to x-frame-options for further google searching.

Comment: @hafichuk aww glad I helped

Answer (score 3):

No, if a site sets the `X-Frame-Options` response header to `DENY` then there is no way for you to override that setting.

It's a security measure to prevent [click-jacking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Types_of_attacks#click-jacking) attacks. You can read more about it in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).